# How to customize oscar address form fields?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

after customizing django oscar app (address) and adding a new field named 'area' when I run migrate it gave me Unknown field(s) (area) specified for UserAddress

I used the command 
`./manage.py oscar_fork_app address myappsfolder/`
after creating the folder and `__init__.py` file in it
then I started to customize the app like this:

```
#myappsfolder/address/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from oscar.apps.address.abstract_models import AbstractAddress

class Address(AbstractAddress):
    area = models.CharField(_("Area"), max_length=120, 
    choices=settings.AREA_CHOICES, blank=True)

from oscar.apps.address.models import *
```

---

```
#myappsfolder/address/forms.py

from oscar.apps.address import forms as base_forms

class UserAddressForm(base_forms.UserAddressForm):
    class Meta(base_forms.UserAddressForm.Meta):
        fields = ['area']
```

I didn't touch the `admin.py` , `config.py` and `__init__.py` that have been created by the command `./manage.py oscar_fork_app address myappsfolder/` 
also the `__init__.py` that I created in `myappsfolder` is empty, should I add something to these files ?

What should I do to customize this app ? or any other app ?
If I edited the models in `oscar/apps/address/abstract_models.py` it only apply in local host  and the error in forms disappear , which means that django still reading the models from `oscar/apps` not from `myappsfolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override `AbstractAddress` in that way because the changes will not propagate to other models such as `UserAddress` that directly subclass `AbstractAddress`. Instead you need to override the specific address models that you want to change. So if you want to change `UserAddress` then override  that particular model:

```
from oscar.apps.address.abstract_models import AbstractUserAddress

class UserAddress(AbstractUserAddress):
    area = models.CharField(_("Area"), max_length=120, choices=settings.AREA_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

... after which your changes to `UserAddressForm` should work.

If you need to override `ShippingAddress` as well, then you will also have to fork the `shipping` app and do the same thing there, because that is where the model lives.

Comment: Thanks for your replying , that works for me and the new field appear on the form but after I choose the area and save , in the Address Book the area isn't there , also at the dashboard it isn't there ,however when I edit the address I can edit the area, how can I make it appear on the customer account and the dashboard ?

Comment: You need to override either [`base_fields`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1cb17f66fd9f8e06c3cba5c5127f63bad85a5941/src/oscar/apps/address/abstract_models.py#L244) or [`active_address_fields()`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1cb17f66fd9f8e06c3cba5c5127f63bad85a5941/src/oscar/apps/address/abstract_models.py#L391) to include the field you have added. Note that changing `base_fields` will alter the address hash which is used to check for duplicates etc.

Comment: @solarissmoke Can you help me out here? How do I hide some unnecessary fields from the address form?